# How to execute code when the user close the session?

Tags: c#

i am writing an application which use  microscope.

When the user close the application, the application turned off the microscope.

Is there a way to execute this code when the application is closed because the user close the windows session ?

Regards,

Comment: What Framework are you using?

Comment: Bear in mind that you don't get to run any code if they pull the power cord out (or hold down the power button), and you need to make your startup robust no matter what state the system was left in. Often, that'll be enough (and you're not under the same time constraints as expected during shutdown)

Comment: I am using .Net Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: Damien : I just wish to turned off the microscop to increase his life.

Comment: @JonathanLeCornichone I meant : Winform, Console App, something else?

Comment: I am using window with Xaml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FormClosing event to catch a form closing action, and perform tasks before closure, or prevent it from closing at all. Here is an example I use regularly.

```
    private void Form_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do stuff here:
        if (prevent_close)
        {
            //or cancel the closing here:
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: this action seems to be launch only when the app is closed. I think closing the session kill the app :/